# Move to 'class.cs'

Tags: c#, resharper

If I start with a new class in a same file as another and then start the action `Move to 'filename.cs'` it always inserts this header:

```cs
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
// See the LICENSE file in the project root for more information.
```

Where is this header coming from? I have searched my hard disk and I cannot find it.

Can I prevent that this header is added?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you can modify the default template for new C# files by going to "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Text Editor" -> "C#" -> "Code Style" -> "File Header". Here, you can modify the default text that is inserted at the top of new files, including removing the license header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it comes from your .editorconfig file, look for the 'file_header_template' rule. See [File header style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/File_Header_Style.html) for more details.